# Is there any way to distinguish the main Thread from any Threads that it spawns?

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point

I know that the `getName()` function on the main thread will return the String `main`, but this can be changed with `setName()`.

Is there any way to always determine the main thread of an application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the main thread has an *id* of `1` as indicated by [`Thread.getId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId()):

```
class test{
    public static boolean isMainThread(){
        return Thread.currentThread().getId() == 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(isMainThread());
        new Thread( new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println(isMainThread());
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it is part of the specification or an implementation-specific feature.

A more portable way is this:

```
class test{

    static long mainThreadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();

    public static boolean isMainThread(){
        return Thread.currentThread().getId() == mainThreadId;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(isMainThread());
        new Thread( new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println(isMainThread());
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

with the caveat that `mainThreadId` has to be either in a class that is loaded by the main thread (e.g. the class containing the `main` method). For instance, this doesn't work:

```
class AnotherClass{
    static long mainThreadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();

    public static boolean isMainThread(){
        return Thread.currentThread().getId() == mainThreadId;
    }
}
class test{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        //System.out.println(isMainThread());
        new Thread( new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println(AnotherClass.isMainThread());
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. I'm guessing this would be implementation specific though since the Thread storage structure isn't defined by the JVM specification.

Comment: Fair enough. On the plus side, this behavior [appears](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.nextThreadID%28%29) as part of the source code for `java.lang.Thread`, so it's not a JVM internal.

Comment: I did not know of that method. It looks like your answer is correct then Vlad! Although the functionality could be overridden by the implementation it's reasonable to assume it wouldn't be!

Comment: @Vlad: What makes you think that the source code for java.lang.Thread is not implementation specific?

Comment: @Jivings: No, it's never reasonable to assume that undocumented behaviour will not change or be consistent across different JavaVM implementations or versions.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't, though Oracle's JDK and the OpenJDK share that bit of functionality. I was saying it's not coming from the JVM itself, e.g. the id being retrieved from the native thread id.

Comment: So you've observed a specific behaviour in two of the tens or so different VM implementations, where the two even share most of the source code and suggest to rely on that behaviour? This is great ...

Comment: According to the Java documentation the threadID is not a good indicator: `When a thread is terminated, the thread ID may be reused.` Therefore if the main thread has ended another thread may get id 1.

Answer (score 9):

One possibility is to call [`Thread.currentThread()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread%28%29) at the start of `main()`, and hold on to the reference.

Comment: Say for example I'm writing a framework, and I have a static method that I only want the main thread to be able to execute?

Comment: Sounds to me like you've got a design issue ;-) If you MUST have this, I would simply document it (like most GUI frameworks document the fact that you can only make UI updates from the event dispatcher thread).

Comment: If you take a look at the Android API. Only the main thread/activity can perform UI changes I believe. Messages can be passed back to the main thread requesting it makes changes but if it's attempted by anything else then an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Jivings: If you situation is similar to GUI frameworks, your problem is slightly different from what you describe. You don't need to identify a main thread, you need to identify a thread that executes a particular piece of code (a message loop in the case of GUI frameworks).

Comment: @axtavt I assumed that would be the main thread, but perhaps not.

Comment: I think comparing `getId()` it with 1 is more reliable than saving the id in `main()`. For example, in EMC Documentum, `static void main(String[] args)` can be called from a servlet thread.

Answer (score 2):

From your question and your responses to comments I would suggest the following 2 approaches:

1. Place all requests to an event queue and main thread will take the
   requests from request queue to call the method you are talking
   about. In this case there must be a contract that any other method
   wanting to access the method you are talking about can do it only
   via the event queue (same idea as EDT).
2. Place an extra parameter in the method that you want to be called by
   main only to act as a token.Inside the method check if the token is
   correct (only `main` will have it/know it).If it is correct then
   proceed.Otherwise return false. Of course if you are allowed to make such a modification

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a reasonable solution.